# Is there a quick way to wrap jQuery around every element in an array?

Tags: jquery

Can this be done in a more concise way?

```
var src = $('div');
var dest = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < src.length; i++)
    dest[i] = $(src[i]);
```

I can only think of this, which is still pretty verbose:

```
var dest = [];
$('div').each(function() { dest.push($(this)); });
```

Does jQuery offer anything better for this case? I can't find it.

---

To address some of the recurring questions in the comments:

> `src[i]` is already a jQuery object, calling `jQuery(src[i])` doesn't do anything.

No, it's a plain DOM node, without any jQuery wrappings at all.

> Just out of curiosity, why do it at all?

Because afterwards I'll need to do quite a lot of mucking around with each element individually. For example, I need to go over all of them to find the tallest one, then set the rest of them to the same height. After that I need to get all their widths and perform some layouting based on that (so each element gets its x & y coordinates based on the widths of other elements). Etc.

All these manipulations are done more easily if I can use the shorthand functions provided by jQuery, but that means that I need to wrap each element individually (`$('div')` only returned a wrapper around **all** of them). And since I need to visit every element multiple times, I'd like to increase performance by wrapping each of them only once, not on every visit.

Comment: `src[i]` is already a jQuery object, calling `jQuery(src[i])` doesn't do anything.

Comment: `$.map($('div'), function(val, i){ return $(val); }` perhaps?

Comment: @Barmar - no, it's a vanilla DOM object.

Comment: No, `$(selector)` returns a jQuery collection, not an array of DOM objects.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do it at all? jQuery objects already act like arrays.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, a jQuery collection, not a collection of jQuery objects. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/5Fzte/

Comment: @Juhana - Because I later need to perform extensive manipulations on each of the selected DOM elements. Operations like retrieving dimensions and mucking around with CSS. This is easier done if the DOM element is wrapped in the jQuery wrapper. If I tried to do it with the jQuery object returned from `$('div')`, it would only affect the first element or all of them (depending on the operation), not every element idividually.

Comment: @Vilx- did you try the `map()` solution?

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. For one, you can access elements in the collection as jQuery objects with [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) (e.g. `src.eq(i)`), or why not just wrap the individual elements in `$()` when needed?

Comment: @Juhanna - I'll need to access each element several times. I don't want to re-wrap it every time, simply for performance reasons.

Comment: Yeah, `.eq()` will take care of that.

Comment: `var jqueryWrappedArray = $.map($('div'), function(val, i){ return $(val); }` - why the argument? - http://jsfiddle.net/2krmm/

Comment: @limelights - Ahh, you know... [the Internet](http://www.shoeboxblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/arguing-again1.jpg). :) Yes, thanks for your solution. It's only marginally better than mine, but at least it's something. :) Anyways, by the general lack of answers I gather that there isn't anything better anyway (I was expecting something like `$('div').superWrap()`). :)

Comment: @Vilx- I understand what you're getting at now. I can't think of any other way to do it, a simple loop is probably the best solution. As far as I know, jQuery doesn't provide any methods to do this.

Comment: @Vilx-, see my answer too. It may help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what the `map()` is for.
You're looping over each element and apply a function to the element and push it onto a new Array.

```
var wrapped  = $.map($('div'), function(){ return $(this); });
```

or for readability

```
var wrapped  = $.map($('div'), function(val, i) {
    return $(val);
});
```

Comment: FWIW, there's also a [`map()` on `jQuery.fn`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), so `$('div').map(function (v, i));` also works.

Comment: @Matt - Sweet. I get a jQuery object wrapping an array of jQuery objects! Perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not re-convert dom node to jQuery object.

You should try something like this,

```
var src = $('div');
var dest = [];

for ( var i = 0, l = src.length; i < l; i++) {
    dest[i] = src.eq(i);
}

console.log(dest);
```

Or even better,

```
var src = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var dest = [];
for ( var i = 0, l = src.length; i < l; i++) {
    dest[i] = $(src[i]);
}
console.log(dest);
```

I am not very good at js perf, but here's a test http://jsperf.com/eq-vs-vs-vanilla